# Indentation in a C# RTB

Tags: c#, formatting, richtextbox

In my C# application I have a rich textbox with one long text string, which looks like this:

[image: RTB text]

What I want is an indentation of the second and third line:

So the text should look like this:

```
1.       Bitte blenden Sie über die Layerpalette alle für
         die Raumverknüpfung notwendigen zusätzlichen Layer
         ein.
```

I tried

```
richtextbox.SelectionIndent = 5
```

but this only indents the whole text (with the '1.').

Is there a possibility to solve this problem in a RTB?

One thing I have to add: it would be no solution to just cut the sentence into three pieces because I use localization strings that have to be in one piece.

Comment: It looks like some sort of non-user editable hint text you want to display. Why do you need it to be a richttextbox and not a label and a textbox, for example?

Comment: Absolutly correct, it will always be just a hint text. At first I just had a normal textbox but I thought with a RTB I could do formatting much better. As simple as it is, you are right, this would be a solution. I think I will do it like you said but I also would like to know if there is another way (a way of just formatting  a RTB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string text ="1.Bitte blenden Sie über die Layerpalette alle für  die Raumverknüpfung notwendigen zusätzlichen Layer ein.";
        int rowMaxLenth = 30;
        int firstRowIndex = 2;
            text = text.Insert(firstRowIndex,"\t");




        for (int i = 1; i < text.Length / rowMaxLenth; i++)
        {

            text= text.Insert((i*rowMaxLenth),"\n\t");
        }
        rchTextbox.Text = text;
```

> But you need some change, are you inserting tab in word or after word

Comment: Unfortunately this is no option for me because I cannot split the string because actually I do not know how long it is (I load it via a localized string chain ==> could be a russion text or whatever)

Comment: you can set row string length, and insert  tab in every row

Comment: Do you have an example of this? I am not really shure what you mean

Comment: I just have to change it a bit so that it does not cut words but all in all this is a good solution. Thank you